# strip null values of json object

Tags: php, json

All my AJAX requests are in json format which are being parsed in javascript.

How can i prevent null values being displayed in an HTML page without needing to write an if-statement in javascript for each json value?

Or should i write a custom PHP function to encode an array to json instead of using json_encode() so it doesn't display 'null' ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In server side with PHP,

You can use [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/array_filter) before [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

`array_filter` without second argument removes *null* elements of entry array, example :

```
$object= array(
             0 => 'foo',
             1 => false,
             2 => -1,
             3 => null,
             4 => ''
          );

$object = (object) array_filter((array) $object);
$result = json_encode($object);
```

The `$result` contains:

```
{"0":"foo","2":-1}
```

As you see, the *null* elements are removed.

Comment: thanks for your answer but this won't work for multidimensional arrays, and removing the keys will result in 'undefined' values

Comment: @Sobek, BTW, You can't remove a value and keep the key at the same time.

Answer (score 21):

I'm going to add to the accepted answer because that will only work if you have a 1 dimensional object or array. If there is any array or object nesting then in order to get the accepted solution to work, you must create some sort of recursive array filter. Not ideal.

The best solution my colleague and I came up with was to actually perform a regular expression on the JSON string before it was returned from the server.

```
$json = json_encode($complexObject);
echo preg_replace('/,\s*"[^"]+":null|"[^"]+":null,?/', '', $json);
```

The regular expression will remove all places in the string of the form `,"key":null` including any whitespace between the leading comma and the start of the key. It will also match `"key":null,` afterwards to make sure that no null values were found at the beginning of a JSON object.

This isn't an ideal solution but it's far better than creating a recursive array filter given an object could be several dimensions deep. A better solution would be if `json_encode` had a flag that let you specify if you wanted null entries to remain in the output string.

Comment: In the end this is what worked for me. I had multidimensional JSON objects. I agree that this would be nice if `json_encode` natively had support for it, but I highly doubt that'll ever happen. PHP tends to be weak with multidimensional anything, at least in my experience.

Comment: This worked for me, but I added ` ?` before each `null` to account for when JSON_PRETTY_PRINT is set and there's a space between the key and value.

Comment: This doesn't work for me for some reason.

Comment: For me it was the simplest solution, but it did not work. After checking the regex I found it expects the colon right after the key, so like `"field":null` which was not the case for me. Also it left the empty lines there which looks weird, so I modified it accordingly:
`/,\s*"[^"]+":null| *"[^"]+"\s*:\s*null\s*,?[\r\n]*/`
This leaves all the values except null and the output still looks well formatted.

Answer (score 10):

To remove *only* `NULL`, but keep `FALSE`, `''`, and `0`:

```
function is_not_null($var)
{
    return !is_null($var);
}

echo json_encode(array_filter((array) $object, 'is_not_null'));
```

Answer (score 5):

```
public function __toString() {
    $obj = clone $this;
    $keys = get_object_vars($obj);
    foreach ($keys as $key => $value) {
        if (!$value) {
            unset($obj->{$key});
        }
    }
    return json_encode($obj);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you may add some comment and explanation, teach us! Just placing your code has less added value.

Comment: @HonzaZidek __toString() is a magic method that gets called when an object is casted to a string.  What is doing is returning a copy of the called object, but first looping through it and unsetting all of its attributes.  You would do something like var_dump((string) $object).

Answer (score 1):

What about using the native JSON.stringify method on the javascript side?
You can set, a second parameter, a function to remove keys with a null value.
If you return undefined, the property is not included in the output JSON string (check the documentation for "the replacer parameter" at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_native_JSON#The_replacer_parameter).

```
function removeNulls(obj) {
    var str = JSON.stringify(obj, function(key, val) {
        if (val == null) return undefined;
        return val;
    });
    return JSON.parse(str);
}
```

Then you can have a "normalized" JSON object by calling:

```
var obj = removeNulls(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

A version that works with multi-dimensional arrays.

```php
$withoutNull = function($a) use (&$withoutNull) {
    return array_filter(
        array_map(
            fn($p) => is_array($p) ? $withoutNull($p) : $p, $a
        )
    );
};
```

Example:

```php
$a = [
    "name" => "nathan",
    "data" => [
        "age" => 27,
        "something" => null
    ],
    "another" => null
];
$b = $withoutNull($a);
print_r($b);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [name] => nathan
    [data] => Array
        (
            [age] => 27
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo json_encode(array_filter((array) $object, function($val) {
    return !empty($val);
}));
```

Comment: Look at the accepted answer: _array_filter without second argument removes null elements of entry array_. So, that is much simpler than your proposal.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Foo implements JsonSerializable
{
    public $param1;
    public $param2;
    
    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return array_filter((array) $this, function ($var) {
            return !is_null($var);
        });
    }
}

public function testJsonSerialization()
{
    $expectedJson = '{"param1":true}';

    $foo = new Foo();
    $foo->param1 = true;
    $foo->param2 = null;

    $this->assertEquals(
        $expectedJson,
        json_encode($foo)
    );
}`
```

of course you can create Abstract class with custom jsonSerialize method and extend all your DTOs from this